# Delete all emails in PowerShell older then 7 month not using Search-Mailbox

Tags: powershell

I have problem with converting my `Search-Mailbox` command to another one. If you all know in the future as `Search-Mailbox` is retired. So I need to use another cmdlet for this command.

Here's My `Search-Mailbox` command:

```
Search-Mailbox -Identity test@test.comm -SearchQuery "(Received:01/12/2017..$((get-date).AddMonths(-7).ToString("MM/dd/yyy")))" -deletecontent
```

What I try to do:

```
    New-ComplianceSearch -Name "Remove older than 7 month messages" -ExchangeLocation test@test.com  -ContentMatchQuery "(Received:01/12/2017..$((get-date).AddMonths(-7).ToString("MM/dd/yyy")))"
    Start-ComplianceSearch -Identity "Remove older than 7 month messages"
    New-ComplianceSearchAction -SearchName "Remove older than 7 month messages" -Purge -PurgeType SoftDelete
```

But don't delete anything and getting error:

```
>Unable to execute the task. Reason: The search "Remove older than 7 month messages" is still running or it didn't return any results. Please wait until the search finishes or edit the query and run the search again.
> + CategoryInfo          : WriteError: (:) [New-ComplianceSearchAction], ComplianceJobTaskException
```

This is one thing what I'm trying. Please help me with this problem, I'm very stuck in here right now.

if i just run this:

```
New-ComplianceSearch -Name "Remove older than 8 month messages" -ExchangeLocation research.shared@covaliscapital.com  -ContentMatchQuery "(Received:01/12/2017..$((get-date).AddMonths(-8).ToString("MM/dd/yyy")))"
Start-ComplianceSearch -Identity "Remove older than 8 month messages"
```

im getting this

```
 RunspaceId                            : sagasgasgasgagsa
    Language                              :
    StatusMailRecipients                  : {}
    LogLevel                              : Suppressed
    IncludeUnindexedItems                 : True
    ContentMatchQuery                     : (Received:01/12/2017..12/04/2019)
    SearchType                            : EstimateSearch
    HoldNames                             : {}
    SearchNames                           : {}
    RefinerNames                          : {}
    Region                                :
    Refiners                              :
    Items                                 : 0
    Size                                  : 0
    UnindexedItems                        : 0
    UnindexedSize                         : 0
    SuccessResults                        : {}
    SearchStatistics                      :
    Errors                                :
    ErrorTags                             : {}
    NumFailedSources                      : 0
    JobId                                 : gasgsagasgasgsagasg
    Name                                  : Remove older than TEST month messages
    CreatedTime                           : 8/4/2020 10:49:45 AM
    LastModifiedTime                      : 8/4/2020 10:49:45 AM
    JobStartTime                          :
    JobEndTime                            :
    Description                           :
    CreatedBy                             : IT Support
    RunBy                                 :
    TenantId                              : asgasgagasgsa
    NumBindings                           : 0
    Status                                : NotStarted
    ExchangeLocation                      : {TEST@TEST.com}
    PublicFolderLocation                  :
    SharePointLocation                    :
    OneDriveLocation                      :
    ExchangeLocationExclusion             :
    PublicFolderLocationExclusion         :
    SharePointLocationExclusion           :
    OneDriveLocationExclusion             :
    JobRunId                              : asgasgag
    Retry                                 : False
    AllowNotFoundExchangeLocationsEnabled : False
    JobOptions                            : 0
    JobProgress                           : 0
    CaseId                                :
    CaseName                              :
    PagingState                           :
    Identity                              : dsaasgfasgsagga
    ContentURL                            :
    ResultInEOP                           : False
    AzureBatchFrameworkEnabled            : False
    IsValid                               : True
    ObjectState                           : New
```

My full powershell script

```
Start-Transcript


$smtpServer="smtp.office365.com" # Office 365 official smtp server 
$from = "IT Support <test@test.com>" # email from  
$logging = "Enabled" # Set to Disabled to Disable Logging 
$testing = "Disabled" # Set to Disabled to Email Users 
$testRecipient = "test@test.com"  
$date = Get-Date -format ddMMyyyy 

$Username = "test@test.com"
$Password = "test-" | ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText -Force
$UserCredential = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -ArgumentList $Username,$Password

$Session = New-PSSession -ConfigurationName Microsoft.Exchange -ConnectionUri  https://eur04b.ps.compliance.protection.outlook.com/powershell-liveid?PSVersion=5.1.17763.1007 -Credential $UserCredential -Authentication Basic –AllowRedirection

 Import-PSSession $Session

Get-ComplianceSearchAction
New-ComplianceSearch -Name "Remove older than 7 month messages" -ExchangeLocation test@test.com  -ContentMatchQuery "(Received:01/12/2017..$((get-date).AddMonths(-7).ToString("MM/dd/yyy")))"
Start-ComplianceSearch -Identity "Remove older than 7 month messages"
New-ComplianceSearchAction -SearchName "Remove older than 7 month messages" -Purge -PurgeType SoftDelete
```

Comment: You might wanna explore the options given in the answer to this question on SO about the same thing: https://stackoverflow.com/a/62678842/3515885

Comment: @notjustme , i see what post before, but he just give some tips for using ```New-ComplianceSearchAction```, but i need set what  command in my situation and i dont know how to do it right. Maybe u can write how it must be like?

Comment: You really should read up on this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/policy-and-compliance/ediscovery/delete-messages?view=exchserver-2019. Also make sure to follow the link on that page to New-ComplianceSearch and read up on the `-ExchangeLocation` parameter.

Comment: @notjustme I read what a lot of time, but i was skipping about what parameter. u think its to be like something like this? ```New-ComplianceSearch -Name "Remove older than 8 month messages" -ExchangeLocation test@test.com  -ContentMatchQuery "(Received:01/12/2017..$((get-date).AddMonths(-8).ToString("MM/dd/yyy")))"
New-ComplianceSearchAction -SearchName "Remove older than 8 month messages" -Purge -PurgeType SoftDelete``` ? But i get error ```Unable to execute the task. Reason: The search "Remove older than 8 month messages" is still running or it didn't
return any results.```

Comment: You've edited your original question so much now it's tricky for me to know at what stage you are in all of this and just what kind of remnants from previous attempts you might be dealing with at the moment.

Comment: @notjustme ohh, sry i want to make this question clear as possible

Answer (score 0):

After *`Start-ComplianceSearch -Identity "Remove older than 7 month messages"`*
ADD :

```
Get-ComplianceSearch -Identity "Remove older than 7 month messages"
Do {
$Get = Get-ComplianceSearch -Identity "Remove older than 7 month messages"
Write-Host "-- CS $($Get.Status), $($Get.Items)"
}
While ($Get.Status -ne 'Completed')
```

So *`New-ComplianceSearchAction -SearchName "Remove older than 7 month messages" -Purge -PurgeType SoftDelete`*  runs after CS completed.