Empty full inbox using PowerShell
I'm an admin and currently trying to empty one of my users inbox which is full, even the archive is.
How can I empty a full mailbox?
I did the following:
Connect-ExhangeOnline -UserPrincipalName <UPN>

Connect-IPPSSession 

Ran this script from a ps1 file
$fecha_limite = Get-Date -Year 2020 -Month 12 -Day 31


$emails = Get-Mailbox -Identity user@company.xyz | Get-MailboxFolderStatistics -FolderScope Inbox | Where-Object { $_.LastModificationTime -lt $fecha_limite }


foreach ($email in $emails) {
    Remove-MailboxItem -Identity $email.Identity
}

Had the following error
ConvertFrom-Json: Conversion from JSON failed with error: Unexpected character encountered while parsing value: U. Path '', line 0, position 0.
I also tried doing a searchQuery in MS Purview which I called "testEmailBackup", export it and downloaded the pst files and proceeded to HardDelete as such:
New-ComplianceSearchAction -SearchName "testEmailBackup" -Purge -PurgeType HardDelete

Then a dashboard is loaded as:
Name                     SearchName         Action RunBy                   JobEndTime        Status
----                     ----------         ------ -----                   ----------        ------
testEmailBackup_Purge testEmailBackup Purge  AdminSoporte 03/6/2024 22:22:41 Starting

I get no response and as it reads in documentation, only deletes like 10 emails per time.

Check if this helps https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62675851/clean-purge-an-exchange-online-mailbox-using-powershell-post-1st-july-2020
